# rotate the marker with move direction

Tags: android, google-maps

Iam developing android app with google map implemented. I have tried to make the marker rotate with the direction of moving (like navigation in google maps) but all tried codes failed. Below are the code. Any suggestion. Note(Iam getting the bearing from method that returns the location, speed and bering and I can see the float value of the bearing changes while changing the direction.

```
                float bearing = setterandGetter.getBearing();
                double lat = setterandGetter.getLatitude();
                double lon = setterandGetter.getLongitude();
                LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(latitudelongitude);

                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentPosition));

Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentPosition).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(blueIcon)).flat(true).rotation(bearing));
```

Comment: Have you putted this code in onLocatioChanged() method?

Comment: yup, the map method is been called when the location changes

Comment: So have you printed log inside that method to check whether it is calling or not?

Comment: yes, it is been calling

Comment: Ok. I have posted an answer. Please refer that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

First of all declare marker varialble globally and initialise it i onCreate with following line :

```
marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentPosition).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(blueIcon)).flat(true).rotation(0));
```

Now add following code in onLocationChanged():

```
map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onMyLocationChange(final Location location) {
       marker.setPosition(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()))
       marker.setRotation(location.getBearing());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `map.clear()` to clear the map and then **create marker** so whenever your Location changed old  marker will automatically  be cleared and new marker is created so it seems like marker is moving with the location

Comment: i want to keep all the previous markers on the map as my app shows the route were driven through, so I cannot clear every marker after locating it.